# Iframe stops working after upgrading to Django 3.2 LTS

Tags: django, iframe

I was using Django 2.2 up till now and I recently tried upgrading to Django 3.2

We use a website live chat plugin called tawk.to which works by embedding an iframe to our page with the chat option in there.

[image]

However, after upgrading to Django 3.2, even though the plugin's JS code is loading, the iframe is missing from the website altogether.
[image]

I am not sure what is causing the issue. Is the iframe blocked in Django 3.2 or do I have to enable any setting for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after going deep into the Django files. Add this to your settings.py file.

```
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin". # when using other websites that track visitors or use their iframe on your website.
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN' # Necessary to show Iframe from your own server (such as PDFs on your website)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are security updates are added in Django 3.2 which do not allow other frames. Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/clickjacking/#preventing-clickjacking.

You should change **X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'** as explained in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/clickjacking/#how-to-use-it

Comment: Tried this but it seems to make no difference. I feel this is telling Django to allow iframes from the same website as mine, so I also tried with X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "*" and X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "ALLOW-FROM *" but nothing seems to work.